# Print event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a project using angular. In my application i need to print the specific area of page. I know we can achieve this using media css but this is creating problem for me beacuse of lot of print functionalities are in the project. I am trying to below the method

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.control.p', ['$event'])
  showPinned(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("modal").innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = 
      "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
      myDiv + "</body>";
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage
}
```

**But when user cancel or confirm then all the events stopped working on application**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you replaced the generated html. But all the event handlers are gone. This makes sense for generating a page for print, but not not restore a fully working page. Either you reload the page or you generate the content for print in a different way. For example by creating a separated document instead of manipulating the existing one.